# How to set row height of a datagridview based on its contents in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to adjust `row` `height` to display entire  contents of a cell(column width is fixed). I have one column and many rows in my datagridview.

I used following codes, but I couldn't get required row height

```
  Me.data.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True  
  data.AutoResizeRows(DtaGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders)
```

Comment: The code you provided works for me. Don't you have a modified cell style for that column?

Comment: I was using custom datagridview column(downloaded from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView ), that datagridview column was not supporting autosizing of rows. Codeproject code is in C# and unfortunately I don't know C# to rectify error and correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set property **AutoSizeColumnMode** of datagridview to **AllCells** and check it.

[DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizerowsmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

try this

```
  DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows[0];
  row.Height = 15;
```

[DataGridViewRow.Height Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.height%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instead:

```
For i=0 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count-1
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Height=50
Next
```

It will consume less time and coding lines

Answer (score 1):

To change the height of the rows you must to make a change to the specific row (On by On) like this

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim r As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(i)
        r.Height = 50
    Next
```